# Switching from sqlite3 to postgres for Django App - 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib

Tags: python, django, postgresql, sqlite

I've done a few things mentioned on stackoverflow for those who have similar problems, but this error just popped up.

I even tried doing a restart, command+R, and then setting csrutil disable.

Then restarting, running python manage.py makemigrations.

It appears though that it's looking 'libpq.5.dylib' in /usr/local/lib/, but it exists on my computer at /usr/lib/libpq.5.6.dylib.

Which is the correct location? Should I just be copying it over?

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 350, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 324, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Users/bchuey/Desktop/portfolio_projects/kallaroo/kallaroo/kallaroo/apps/accounts/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from django.contrib.auth.base_user import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py", line 49, in <module>
    class AbstractBaseUser(models.Model):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 108, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 299, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 263, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 212, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 116, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error loading psycopg2 module: %s" % e)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading psycopg2 module: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libpq.5.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'admin',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

Comment: Show your settings.py. It seems you have improperly configured DB.

Comment: This is not an initial DB setup. There is data already in the sqlite DB. And there are image files in the /media folder.

Comment: Have you ever made a backup of SQlite DB? (dumpdata & syncdb) and after load it into postgres (loaddata)? If not that's why you are getting "image not found".

Comment: I have not. I will try that.

Comment: Ok, so I ran `python manage.py datadump > datadump.json`. Changed my settings.py to point at a postgres database. Then did `python manage.py loaddata datadump.json`. Still spit out the same error after `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Comment: I guess you have (maybe) accidentally deleted an image and yet in th DB is still the path to the image.